# How to print result?

Tags: java

HI I have sth like this:

```
          case 9:

            vehicleList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Vehicle::getMileage));
           // System.out.println(here);
            break;
```

How to print result of that sorting?

Comment: `System.out.println(vehicleList);`

Comment: Since simply printing the list seems so very obvious, perhaps you need this too: [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

```java
vehicleList.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getMileage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it output, you can either output the entire list like this:

```
    System.out.println(vehicleList);
```

This will call `toString()` on every element of `vehicleList` and display it in a single line. If you want each entry on its own line, you can put it into a loop:

```
    for(Vehicle vehicle : vehicleList)
    {
        System.out.println(vehicle);
    }
```

As mentioned by Andreas, in order to avoid getting a meaningless string of characters when you output your `Vehicle`, make sure to implement a `toString()` method in the class that returns a `String`.